# How do I assign values to variables which comprise a matrix?

Tags: code

I have a m x n matrix (5 x 5) and I wish to assign values for m1,m2, m3, etc and n1, n2, and n3 etc, without changing the a[m x n] values.  I'm not looking so much for a direct solution but maybe a place to start because I'd like to try it myself first, I'm just a little lost as to where to start.

Comment: This is possible, but I suppose the big question is why? Indexing will work just as well if not better

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Perhaps you can give us an idea of what you are trying to achieve? For me it is a bit difficult to tell based on your question. Please also show the code of what you have tried.

Comment: Hi, so to add on to what I have written above, I have a probability distribution and from that distribution I used RandomVariate to get me 10 values.  What I want to do is from that pool of 10 numbers, I'd like to randomly assign those numbers to m and n for m 1-5 and also for n 1-5, but I don't wish to change the elements in the matrix itself.  The matrix elements (the a[m x n]) I have represent whether a connection exists between m and n (i.e. an adjacency matrix) but the values I want to attach to m1-5 and n1-5 represent something different.  I'm trying to figure out the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ReplacePart`. For example, for the $5\times5$ matrix defined as

```
matrix = Array[m, {5, 5}];
```

we can replace $m_{23}$ as

```
newMatrix = ReplacePart[matrix, {2, 3} -> 0];
```

Explicitly:

> $matrix\;=\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  m(1,1) & m(1,2) & m(1,3) & m(1,4) & m(1,5) \\
>  m(2,1) & m(2,2) & m(2,3) & m(2,4) & m(2,5) \\
>  m(3,1) & m(3,2) & m(3,3) & m(3,4) & m(3,5) \\
>  m(4,1) & m(4,2) & m(4,3) & m(4,4) & m(4,5) \\
>  m(5,1) & m(5,2) & m(5,3) & m(5,4) & m(5,5) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

and

> $newMatrix\;= \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  m(1,1) & m(1,2) & m(1,3) & m(1,4) & m(1,5) \\
>  m(2,1) & m(2,2) & 0 & m(2,4) & m(2,5) \\
>  m(3,1) & m(3,2) & m(3,3) & m(3,4) & m(3,5) \\
>  m(4,1) & m(4,2) & m(4,3) & m(4,4) & m(4,5) \\
>  m(5,1) & m(5,2) & m(5,3) & m(5,4) & m(5,5) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$